# Background Agent disabled from phone's settings

Tags: windows-phone-7, settings, windows-phone-7.1, background-agent

My application makes use of a Background Agent to do a periodic task. As told in the background agents' guidelines, I offer the user the choice to enable/disable this feature. I use a ToogleSwitch control with its isChecked property bound. However, I do not know how to detect if user has disabled the agent from phone's settings; should I delete and reschedule the agent each time to check it?

Thanks,

Eddie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check it. Your task is to create app that will work in any condition, even if `Background Agent` is disabled.

UPD:

[Detecting When Background Agents Have Been Disabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: I just want to check it to show my ToogleSwitch in a coherent state with the OS setting. And I would prefer not to reschedule to respect the agents timing.

Comment: Just found what you was looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944(v=vs.92).aspx